# Eigen Instantiation of Dynamic Matrix Encountering OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG During Compilation

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a class that uses a dynamic Eigen::Matrix of doubles (i.e. Eigen::MatrixXd ), that has max rows and cols specified at compile time.
During use, the dimensions may be less than the maximum.  The purpose of specifying the max rows and cols is to avoid dynamic reallocation using the heap if the matrix size increases.

When I compile the code, I get an OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG error.  I'm using Eigen 3.2 and VisualStudio 2017 with the default options and flags.  This error occurs whether in Debug or Release mode.  The Target arch is x64.

Here's the code (simplified):

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();
 
private:
  // Create a member that is an Eigen::Matrix of doubles w/ dynamic sizing and max rows and cols 
  // at compile time = 1024.
  Eigen::Matrix< double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, 0, 1024, 1024 > x;

  // Eigen::MatrixXd x(1024, 1024); // -- FAILS too!
};
```

What appears to be happening is that during the template expansion, the dynamic nature of the array declaration is ignored and the expansion thinks it is a static array which causes the size checking in `Eigen::internal::check_static_allocation_size()` to assert.  I'm not sure why the dynamic flags/constants are being ignored.

Thanks,

--Mike

Comment: How will your matrix resize at runtime? Incrementally adding rows/columns? Randomly growing and shrinking? Is one dynamic allocation at the beginning ok?

Comment: The typical resize behavior is that the number of rows and cols increase for a while then hit a steady state point where the changes fluctuate around an average value for each.  The deltas are usually w/in +/- 10 for each.

Answer (score 1):

This is shown [in the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html)

> ABI and storage layout
>
> The table below summarizes the ABI of some possible Matrix instances which is fixed thorough the lifetime of Eigen 3.
>
> ...

```cpp
Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic,0,MaxRows,MaxCols>
```

> Equivalent C structure

```cpp
struct {
  T data[MaxRows*MaxCols];  // with (size_t(data)%A(MaxRows*MaxCols*sizeof(T)))==0
  Eigen::Index rows, cols;
 };
```

Eg, you're specifying dynamic matrix with a constant size container (for speed probably). But that container is a C-array and thus allocated on the place where you allocate your object. Which is likely on the stack. 1024x1024 elements of a 8-byte double is too large for the stack.

You should just use `Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>` for an allocated dynamic matrix.

Edit:

If you want to pre-allocate memory for your dynamic matrix, use the `resize` member function. You can for example do that in the constructor.

```cpp
x.resize(1024, 1024);
```

Edit 2:

I'm not sure if resizing the matrix can ever be done without reallocation. You could look into [`conservativeResize`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a712c25be1652e5a64a00f28c8ed11462)

> Resizes the matrix to rows x cols while leaving old values untouched.
> The method is intended for matrices of dynamic size. If you only want to change the number of rows and/or of columns, you can use conservativeResize(NoChange_t, Index) or conservativeResize(Index, NoChange_t).
> Matrices are resized relative to the top-left element. In case values need to be appended to the matrix they will be uninitialized.

Comment: What you stated is correct.  I'm looking to specify a dynamic matrix w/ a constant size container.  Using Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> creates a dynamic matrix, but w/ initial size of zero, which is not what is desired/required.  The purpose of the constant size is to avoid on the fly dynamic allocation if the matrix grows.

Comment: @BlueEnamel see my edit.

Comment: That will work.  I'm still curious as to why the original code throws the error.  Based on the documentation, that should do what I want.

Comment: @BlueEnamel OK, i tried to clarify that in my answer. No, I'm afraid you're misunderstanding the documentation or you don't know that 1024x1024x8 bytes do not fit on the stack.

Comment: I see the misunderstanding on my end regarding fixed vs. dynamic size.  The documentation states:  "Dynamic-size means that the numbers of rows or columns are not necessarily known at compile-time. In this case they are runtime variables, and the array of coefficients is allocated dynamically on the heap."  I was expecting that using "Dynamic" for the row and col sizes, would produce the behavior I wanted.  However, it looks like if maxRows and maxCols are specified, the template tries to create a fixed size matrix.  The equivalent C structure example shows what occurs under the hood.

Comment: Unfortunately, conservativeResize() is an Eigen 3.4 method.  I'm stuck with version 3.2.  I am somewhat surprised that there isn't an options flag to handle the case where a large matrix is needed, but the allocation is only desired to happen once.  Essentially a heap based version of Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic, 0, maxRows, maxCols>.

Comment: `conservativeResize` will not actually help you, since that only means that it will conserve the values which were stored before resizing (it could actually cause allocations, where a normal `resize` does not, e.g. when resizing a `512x1024` to `1024x512`).